# OpenBUGS Code gives error 'expected a comma'

Tags: bayesian, winbugs

I am trying to fit a hierarchical model using OpenBUGS, with the following code:

```
model 
{   
for( i in 1:n){
    tausq[i] <- 1/pow(sigma[i], 2)
    psi[i] ~ dnorm(psi, tausq)
    psihat[i] ~ dnorm(psi[i], tausq[i])
}   
psi  ~ dnorm(0, 1000)
tausq ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
sigmasq <- 1/tausq
}

#data

list(n = 12,
psihat = c(1.055, -0.097, 0.626, 0.017, 1.068, -0.025, -0.117, -0.381, 0.507, 0.00,     3.85, 4.05),
sigma = c(0.373, 0.116, 0.229, 0.117, 0.471, 0.120, 0.220, 0.239, 0.186, 0.328, 0.206, 0.254)) 

# initial values

list(psi = 1.5, sigmsq=.1)
```

But, I get the error 'expected a comma', and OpenBUGS highlights tausg in the psi[i] ~... statement. I am currently at a loss for what I am doing wrong. Other models fit fine, so I don't think this is a larger program issue.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining `psi` and `tausq` twice which is confusing BUGS. Once as a vector of values (`psi[i] ~` and `tausq[i] ~`) and once as a single values (`psi ~` and `tausq ~`). You need to relabel one or the other,... probably the later to something like `psi.mean ~` and `tausq.mean ~` or `psi0 ~` and `tausq0 ~`.